# Excel - Turning a negative number into a null

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get the change percentage between 2 numbers and that giver result must have 2 decimal places. Currently the formula I am using is `=(Value_2-Value_1)/Value_2` and the result is **0.00%**.
Of course that by looking to the column `Value_1` and `Value_2` we know the result of that formula isn't exactly **0.00%**. In fact, it's **-0.0044...**. So it's not `Null`, but I want it to be.

[image]

I have another column called `Null` and there I have a formula that returns an **X** if the "Change" column value is equal to "0". `=IF(Change=0, "X", "")`. Obviously this isn't returning the **X**, because the value ins't negative.

[image]

My question is...How do I turn this "0.00%" which in fact is "0.0044...%" to be a null?

Comment: So does anything below (a positive) `0.01` needs to be rounded to 0? I'm not quite getting what *exact* rule you want to apply.

Comment: I would rather do a formula that returns me "0.00%" if the 2 decimal places are"00". You know?

Comment: So you mean `=IF(ABS(A1)<0.0001,0,A1)`. Since `0.01%` equals 0.0001

Comment: F* it. I am always finding ways to make it difficult and you find a pretty easy solution. Thanks you!

Comment: =) Sometimes it takes a second pair of eyes. I've noted my comment as an answer.

Comment: Yea :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, since `0.01%` equals `0.0001` we can use:

```
=IF(ABS(A1)<0.0001,0,A1)
```